# How to dynamically create VCS or ICS file (Outlook)?

Tags: java, calendar, outlook

I have been reading about this from some days but I have not found anything java related. The idea is that I need to send (program or email) some appointments to the users outlook calendar. Firstly I searched about a way to do this through programatically sending appointments to exchange server. From what I found, that option is almost not possible. So I thought about creating a VCS appointments file, and then the user will have to double click and add those events. I know how to create a VCS file, or to import it from outlook and use it in another user but I need to create a VCS file from some records that are stored in a database. Does anyone know how to do this in Java? Can anyone suggest me any tutorial/page/option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create ics files You should look for [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) library for Java. I used [ICal4j](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/wiki) to create simple events that could be imported to outlook. Project has wiki with [code examples](https://ical4j.github.io/ical4j-user-guide/examples/).